# Proguard is shrinking position of viewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, proguard

I am using AndroidX viewpager having multiple clickable views on it.
Everything is working perfectly in debug the `application` when `proguard` is not enabled but when I enable `minifyEnabled true` for release `application` view of Viewpager is not getting changed.
Looking for proguard rules to keep viewpager position?

Like I have a button and animation, whenever I click the button animation should play.

```
    private fun getCurrentView(viewPager: ViewPager): View? {
    try {
        val currentItem = viewPager.currentItem
        for (i in 0 until viewPager.childCount) {
            val child = viewPager.getChildAt(i)
            val layoutParams = child.layoutParams as ViewPager.LayoutParams
            val f: Field =
                layoutParams.javaClass.getDeclaredField("position") //NoSuchFieldException
            f.isAccessible = true
            val position = f.get(layoutParams) as Int //IllegalAccessException
            if (!layoutParams.isDecor && currentItem == position) {
                return child
            }
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is you need to protect the `ViewPager.LayoutParams#position` from obfuscation and shrink with following `ProGuard` rules if you enable ProGuard or R8 will keep your position.

```
-keep class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams { int position; }
```